# Average formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm new to data analytics and have a table in front of me with unitstocks.
The numbers are separated with a period after to mark, if its an 18.00 or a 120.00 for e.g. when I use the formula average on Google Sheets though, the number I get is 44760 without a period. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

That number (44760) is a date in raw format (i.e., 44,760 days since the origin date of December 30, 1899... which comes out to July 18, 2022). Try selecting the cell(s) and setting the format to a number format with two decimal places using **Format > Number > Number**. Likely, the cell will then show 7.18 or 18.7 depending on your international locale.